# How do I export TextFileReader object to txt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I read a census ACS file into iPython Notebook in chunks using:

```
pusb = pd.read_csv('ss14pusb.csv', low_memory=False, chunksize = 25000)
```

Then I selected some columns I want to keep and use for analysis. Now I want to export `pusb` to a txt or csv file, but `pusb.to_csv(etc... didn't work. How do I do this? Is there a way to concatenate the chunks one I read them so that they're one data frame?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can try function [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
pusb = pd.read_csv('ss14pusb.csv', low_memory=False, chunksize = 25000)
print pusb
#<pandas.io.parsers.TextFileReader object at 0x00000000150E0048>
df = pd.concat(tp, ignore_index=True)
```

I think is necessary add parameter `ignore index` to function `concat`, because avoiding duplicity of indexes.

I try explain it better:

```
pusb = pd.read_csv('ss14pusb.csv', low_memory=False, chunksize = 25000)
```

function read `csv` by chunks - [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#iterating-through-files-chunk-by-chunk) and output is `TextFileReader`, not `DataFrame`.

You can check this iterable object by:

```
for chunk in pusb:
    print(chunk)
```

And then you need `concat` chunks to one big `DataFrame` - use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html).

[Concatenating objects](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#concatenating-objects).

Comment: ValueError: No objects to concatenate

Comment: Try check `for chunk in pusb: print(chunk)`

Comment: It doesn't come back with an error but I don't really understand what it did (and there doesn't seem to be an output). Do you mind explaining it for a rookie?

Comment: [Docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#iterating-through-files-chunk-by-chunk), I think problem can be with `chunksize = 25000`, maybe try decrease number.